# Django social and site-local token-based authorization

Tags: python, django, authorization, django-allauth, python-social-auth

I'm developing a web service on Django, and I want to make a token-based registration feature (to make it mobile-ready).

After doing some searching, I found that there's a some beautiful ready to use applications:

- [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), with social authorization (facebook, twitter, google+,
  etc.) and site-local authorization (username/email/password), but it
  doesn't have built-in integration with API and it is not token-based.
- [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) or [django-rest-framework-social-oauth2](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2), which are well-tested solutions, but they doesn't have a site-local registration (social only)

So, could you please give me some links, or some hints how to implement this? I'm very new to django and python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a very nice tutorial at [httplambda.com](http://httplambda.com/a-rest-api-with-django-and-oauthw-authentication/), but it is not so newbie-friendly in my opinion